# MYSQL not starting

Tags: mysql

Here is a my error log file

```
[localhost:local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64/data] root# sudo localhost.err localhost1.err
130911 14:16:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
130911 14:16:25 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
130911 14:16:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130911 14:16:25 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130911 14:16:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130911 14:16:25 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130911 14:16:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130911 14:16:25 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130911 14:16:25 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 6489730180
130911 14:16:25  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 6489785073
130911 14:16:25  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 130911 14:16:25 - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16384
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error is telling you that it ran out of memory. You could start up `top` or `htop` in another window when you repeat this restart and see if that's actually the case that it's running out of RAM.